# Use typescript generic typing to set function argument type based on sibling-field in object

Tags: typescript, function, generics

I want to create a typescript function called `wrapper` which is called with the following argument.

```
wrapper({

  keyOne: {
    payload: {
      someField: 'foo'
    },
    caller: (payload1) => {...}
  },

  keyTwo: {
    payload: {
      someOtherField: 2
    },
    caller: (payload2) => {...}
  },

  keyThree: {...},

  keyFour: {...},
  
  ...

})
```

Each key-value in the argument object is of type:

```
{
  payload: Record<string, string | number>,
  caller: (payloadArg) => void
}
```

---

How do use generic typing to set the type of each individual `payloadArg` argument to the corresponding `payload` field above?

---

- The type of the `payload1`-argument should be of type `{ someField: string }`
- The type of the `payload2`-argument should be of type `{ someOtherField: number }`

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do, but there is more room for improvement since the generic type still has to be manually entered.

```
interface Caller<T extends Record<string, string | number>> {
  payload: T,
  caller: (payloadArg: this['payload']) => void
}
var caller: Caller<{ someField: string }> = {
    payload: {
        someField: 'foo'
    },
    caller: (payload1) => {} // parameter is of type { someField: string }
};
```